# Create XML File With Dynamic Sub Elements Level In C#

Tags: c#, xml, multi-level

there is Tree View In C# Project Contains Dynamic Level Of Categories
And Products Belong Only One Category

Application Create Only Parent Category With Single level Of Sub Category

So that we need is Create XML File With Multiple Sub Categories

Code :

```
    private void createXmlFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<PRG.CreateXML.Category> categories = Service.Category.Instance.FindAll();
            List<PRG.CreateXML.Product> products = Service.Product.Instance.FindAll();
            string fileName = "Category.xml";
            string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data\\" + fileName;
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 3;
            writer.WriteStartElement("data");
            createXMLCategoryFirstLevel(writer, categories, products);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();

            createXMLProductDetails(products);

            MessageBox.Show("Create XML File Success!\nThe File Address:\n" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\data");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error In Creat XML File. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void createXMLCategoryFirstLevel(XmlTextWriter writer, List<PRG.CreateXML.Category> categories, List<PRG.CreateXML.Product> products)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (PRG.CreateXML.Category category in categories)
            {
                if (category.ParentId == null)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Category");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("ID");
                    writer.WriteString(category.ID.ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
                    writer.WriteString(category.Name);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Image");
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category.Image))
                    {
                        writer.WriteString(category.Image.Replace(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\", ""));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.WriteString("");
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Description");
                    writer.WriteString(category.Description);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    createXMLSubCategory(writer, categories, category.ID, products);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void createXMLSubCategory(XmlTextWriter writer, List<PRG.CreateXML.Category> categories, long parentID, List<PRG.CreateXML.Product> products)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (PRG.CreateXML.Category category in categories)
            {
                if (category.ParentId == parentID)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("SubCategory");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("ID");
                    writer.WriteString(category.ID.ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
                    writer.WriteString(category.Name);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Image");
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category.Image))
                    {
                        writer.WriteString(category.Image.Replace(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\", ""));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.WriteString("");
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Description");
                    writer.WriteString(category.Description);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("ParentId");
                    writer.WriteString(category.ParentId.ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    // We Added This Two9 Lines But Error occured
                    // createXMLSubCategory(writer, categories, category.ID, products);
                    // writer.WriteEndElement();
                    createXMLProduct(writer, products, category.ID);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void createXMLProduct(XmlTextWriter writer, List<PRG.CreateXML.Product> products, long categoryID)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (PRG.CreateXML.Product product in products)
            {
                if (product.CategoryID == categoryID)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Product");
                    writer.WriteStartElement("ID");
                    writer.WriteString(product.ID.ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
                    writer.WriteString(product.Name);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("CategoryID");
                    writer.WriteString(product.CategoryID.ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Image");
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(product.Image))
                    {
                        writer.WriteString(product.Image.Replace(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\", ""));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.WriteString("");
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Description");
                    writer.WriteString(product.Description);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

```
                createXMLSubCategory(writer, categories, category.ID, products);
                // writer.WriteEndElement();
```